# Reactively/Dynamically change children's Stack order

Tags: flutter

I have a Stack with a dynamic List of widget as children reactive thanks to GetX package.

```
Stack(
      children: [
        Obx(
          () => Stack(
            children: controller.pagesStack,
          ),
        ),
        TopBar(),
        Positioned(
          bottom: Get.width * 0.01,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Center(child: Dock()),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

In my controller I change the order of Widget in the list pagesStack to render the last widget pressed to the top of my Stack. But it doesn't rebuild/refresh the UI.

```
class WebHomeController extends GetxController {
  var pagesStack = <WebApp>[].obs;

  openOrHideApp(WebApp webApp) {
    if (pagesStack.isNotEmpty) {
      pagesStack.firstWhere((element) => element.isTop.value).isTop.value =
          false;
    }
    pagesStack.add(webApp);
  }

  putAppOnTopStack(String appName) {
    pagesStack.firstWhere((webApp) => webApp.isTop.value).isTop.value = false;
    int indexToMove =
        pagesStack.indexWhere((webApp) => webApp.appName == appName);
    pagesStack[indexToMove].isTop.value = true;

    pagesStack.add(pagesStack.removeAt(indexToMove));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After passing more than 10 hours, I have found the solution thanks to [this](https://devstory.net/13107/flutter-stack) French website.

If you encounter the same issue:

When the number and the order changes continuously or often in a Stack, your children's Stack need Key.

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => controller.addNewWidgetToMyStack(
      WebApp(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        appName: appName,
        isTop: true.obs,
      ),
    ),
    child: PhysicalModel(..........
```

In the example above, the important element is : **key: UniqueKey(),**